# Пустые GET POST при ajax запросе.

Tags: ajax, php

Выглядит так.

```
var jqxhr =  $.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "/registration_ajax.php",
data: "email="+ значение,
})
;
```

Запрос доходит до сервера и возвращает всё правильно.
Но PHP имеет пустые GET и POST массивы.

В отладчике браузера указывается, запрос такой:
http//192.168.0.3/registration_ajax.php?email=rr@mail.ru

Насколько помню, ошибка кроется в ip 192.168.0.3. Если использовать доменное имя или внешний ip, то проблем не будет по идее. Но я помню, что эту ошибку исправлял и использовал локальный ip. Может нужные какие то опции jquery ajax?

Comment: в .htaccess редиректы стоят?

Comment: В смысле вот такие настройки Access-Control-Allow-Methods?
Не стоят. Можно ли обойтись без них? только за счёт настроек jquery?

Comment: нет, я имел ввиду редиректы. заголовки типа Access-Control, здесь вообще не причем. скорей всего проблема в конфигурации сервера. не могу вспомнить в практике ситуации когда бы адреса представленные в десятичном формате ipv4 воспринимались некорректно.

Comment: Ну вот в массиве `$_REQUEST PHP данные есть Array ( [email] => rr@mail.ru )`.
А в $_GET $_POST нет. Может нужно что то в php.ini включить?